# Double authentication mechanism: SSO and DB credentials

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, single-sign-on

I've a Java Spring Web application (no Spring Boot) with a "standard" authentication mechanism using database user credentials (It uses Spring Security lib).

Now I need to know if is it possible to include a second auth method with an external Identity Provider and a SSO login.

For example: A user with a specific e-mail domain ex: userX@domain1.com, login with his DB credentials but another type of user (ex: userY@domain2.com) need to be able to login against an external IDP.

I've already developed a bunch of application with [Spring Security SAML](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-saml#overview) lib with ADFS or OpenAM but that was the only login method for all the users.

If is it possibile, how I need to setup the Spring Security Configuration in order to achive this? Maybe I should use a multi-provider config?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting multiple authentication mechanisms can be achieved by checking the user domain and redirecting to your own service that supports UserNamePassword based DB authentication or redirecting to the SSO service.

And for configuring Spring Security, you can create separate implementations extending

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider

[Checkout this link that guides on how to implement multiple authentication mechansism](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers)

For SSO specificly, you have to configure a **redirectURL** with the SSO provider, that internally calls your API with the SAML response.

[SSO with spring security](https://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2)